# Instalação de dependências no npm começam mas nao terminam

Tags: node.js, rest, react, npm, babel

Estou fazendo um curso e acompanhando um livro de *NodeJs*. No livro me pedem para instalar os módulos *Express e *Babel*, já no curso pedem para instalar dependências de uma aplicação que eles disponibilizam.

Meu problema é o seguinte:

> Em ambos os casos quando vou fazer as instalações elas começam, mas não terminam.

Segue os anexos dos prints e link para o diretorio do projeto do livro.

Prints Livro:

[image: erro ao tentar instalar o babel]

Prints Curso:

[image: erro ao tentar instalar as dependências do backend]
[image: erro ao tentar instalar as dependências do frontend]

Comment: Como nao houve nenhum erro, acho que o problema e' o seu terminal. Ja tentou apertar qualquer tecla? No terminal do Windows eu tinha esse problema de ficar travado ate eu apertar qualquer tecla. Aperta ENTER e me diz. Se ainda tiver problema, comenta como voce instalou o Node.

Comment: Já sim, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Eu baixei o no node.js pelo site mesmo e instalei a versão 6.10.0 LTS

Comment: Quanto tempo voce ja esperou? Talvez so seja esperar.

Comment: Esperei algo em torno de 20 a 30 min

Comment: Será q não é algum problema de rede?

Answer (score 1):

O módulo `babel` foi substituido pelo `babel-cli`, sendo assim, você deve instalar o babel usando este comando:

`npm install --save babel-cli`
ou
`npm i -S babel-cli`

Comment: Ok, obrigada consegui fazer a instalação.

Comment: Você poderia me ajudar em mais uma coisa? Quando vou fazer a instalação das dependencias pelo npm i, sempre demora muito e do lado da dependecia aparece a mensagem checking installable status, vc saberia me dizer o pq que isso acontece? Já cheguei a esperar algumas horas e nada acontencer

Comment: Isso pode ser alguma restrição de rede, tem [uma thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9846) aberta no github sobre isso. Se vc está usando windows, pode ser alguma configuração de firewall.

Comment: Já desativei o firewall do windows e continuo com o mesmo problema.

Comment: você teria alguma outra solução?

Comment: Existe uma alternativa ao npm que faz a instalação de modulos de forma diferente e mais rápida, porém totalmente compativel com qq projeto node, chama-se [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/). Ele basicamente é um cli por cima do npm, porém com algumas coisas a mais.